# has and belongs to many rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-4, has-and-belongs-to-many

When I create a new group in my application I want the logged in user(Devise) to be associated with automatically. More users can be added to the group later on aswell. One user can have many groups. One group can have many users.

How do I associate the logged in user on creation?

My group.rb:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users
    has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end
```

groups_controller.rb (create)

```
  def create
    @group = Group.new(group_params)
    @group.users.id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @group.save
        format.html { redirect_to @group, notice: 'Group was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @group }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @group.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And group_params from groups_controller.rb

```
def group_params
      params.require(:group).permit(:name, { :user_ids => [] },)
    end
```

My schema.rb contains:

```
  create_table "groups", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "background"
    t.integer  "clocktype"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "groups_users", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "group_id"
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  add_index "groups_users", ["group_id"], name: "index_groups_users_on_group_id"
  add_index "groups_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_groups_users_on_user_id"
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password"
    t.string   "avatar"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following would add the current user to the created group:

```
# In controller after @group.save
@group.users << current_user
```

See the association method [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-and-belongs-to-many-association-reference) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

@group.user_ids = [current_user.id]

Comment: Your answer is right. Tilhom's answer seems less work-aroundish though. Thanks nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
@group = Group.new(group_params)
@group.users = User.where(:id => current_user.id)
@group.save
```